# Matching String in a List of Strings

Tags: python, string, list

I basically want to create a new list 'T' which will match if each element in the list 'Word' exists as a separate element in the list 'Z'.
ie I want the output of 'T' in the following case to be T = ['Hi x']

```
Word = ['x']
Z = ['Hi xo xo','Hi x','yoyo','yox']
```

I tried the following code but it gives me all sentences with words having 'x' in it however I only want the sentences having 'x' as a separate word.

```
for i in Z:
    for v in i:
        if v in Word:
            print (i)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: what output do you want?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Just to confirm, if `Word` would be `['Hi', 'x']` you would still expect the same output `['Hi x']`?

Answer (score 2):

Just another pythonic way

```
[phrase for phrase in Z for w in Word if w in phrase.split()]
['Hi x']
```

Comment: This looks better, hope OP gets this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with list comprehension.

```
>>> [i for i in Z if any (w.lower() ==j.lower() for j in i.split() for w in Word)]
['Hi x']
```

---

Edit:

Or you can do:

```
>>> [i for i in Z for w in Word if w.lower() in map(lambda x:x.lower(),i.split())]
['Hi x']
```

Comment: Hi can you also edit this code to make it applicable for lowercase words for both lists 'Word' & 'Z', ie i dont want to differentiate b/w 'Work' and 'work'.

Comment: @InheritedGeek, sorry, there was a typo, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
words = ['x']
phrases = ['Hi xo xo','Hi x','yoyo','yox']
for phrase in phrases:
    for word in words:
        if word in phrase.split():
            print(phrase)
```

Comment: `Word` was a list in OP's question, not a single string.

Comment: Now, you will print `Hi xo xo` twice if `words` contains `xo`. See my solution :)

Comment: Did you run the program? It only prints once.

Comment: Oh, ok. My bad.

Comment: No problem, I ran it again just to be sure. You're making me second guess myself xD.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print all strings from `Z` that contain a word from `Word`:

```
Word = ['xo']
Z = ['Hi xo xo','Hi x','yoyo','yox']

res = []
for i in Z:
    for v in i.split():
        if v in Word:
            res.append(i)
            break
print(res)
```

Notice the `break`. Without the break you could get some strings from `Z` twice, if two words from it would match. Like the `xo` in the example.

The `i.split()` expression splits `i` to words on spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you would store `Word` as a `set` instead of `list` you could use `set` operations for check. Basically following splits every string on whitespace, constructs `set` out of words and checks if `Word` is subset or not.

```
>>> Z = ['Hi xo xo','Hi x','yoyo','yox']
>>> Word = {'x'}
>>> [s for s in Z if Word <= set(s.split())]
['Hi x']
>>> Word = {'Hi', 'x'}
>>> [s for s in Z if Word <= set(s.split())]
['Hi x']
```

In above `<=` is same as [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset).